# Handle access violations in COM interop

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop

My managed app is using COM interop. Unfortunately there is a bug in the COM component that causes access violation. When the bug is hit, the whole app crashes, the handler attached to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` didn't get a chance to run. I wonder if there is a way to handle the AV, show a friendly message to the user and recover the managed app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is NO way to "handle" an Access Violation.

Depending on the component you are using and how it is implemented even isolating it inside a second AppDomain might still crash your process - AppDomains are "only" a .NET-thing, from the native perspective of the OS they are NOT isolated.

IF you have some problematic component you can always make your usage of it more robust by using the following approach:

Create a process (EXE) which wraps the usage of that component and exposes an API (for example via any IPC mechanism). You can then start that EXE as a separate process (from your main EXE) and use it... IF you need to kill that component after a certain time and/or when some condition is met you can always kill that "wrapper EXE" from your main EXE... depending on the specific component it might even be useful to implement some special "cleanup code" (possibly in a separate thread) within that "wrapper EXE" which gets executed when you need to kill that "wrapper EXE".

Since you are implementing this in .NET you can even have that "wrapper EXE" as "embedded resource" in your main executable and start it even from RAM without writing it to the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

There is fundamentally no way to "handle" an Access Violation. You have no way to know which memory the COM component has trashed before it sent the AV.

The only thing you can do with a component like this is to try to run it in a separate AppDomain. That way, if it crashes, it only crashes one AppDomain.